# Como acessar valor dropdonw sem refresh

Tags: php, javascript, combobox

Existe um meio de pegar o valor da opção escolhida do meu select, na mesma página, sem enviar o formulário, no momento em que o usuário faz um alteração?

```
<select id="s_um" name="s_um">
                <option id="um_1" value="0"> 0 </option>
                <option id="um_2" value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option id="um_3" value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option id="um_4" value="3"> 3 </option>
                </select>

<select id="s_dois" name="s_dois">
                <option id="dois_1" value="0"> 0 </option>
                <option id="dois_2" value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option id="dois_3" value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option id="dois_4" value="3"> 3 </option>
                </select>
```

Gostaria de somar os valores escolhidos.

Comment: Já pensou em usar jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer assim com jQuery:

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  alert($(this).val()); // ou text()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s_um" name="s_um">
  <option id="um_1" value="0">0</option>
  <option id="um_2" value="1">1</option>
  <option id="um_3" value="2">2</option>
  <option id="um_4" value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="s_dois" name="s_dois">
  <option id="dois_1" value="0">0</option>
  <option id="dois_2" value="1">1</option>
  <option id="dois_3" value="2">2</option>
  <option id="dois_4" value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Ou em javascript:

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

Veja funcionando em:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/sfawg94v/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$('#s_dois').change(function() {

var soma = parseInt($('#s_um option:selected').val()) + parseInt($('#s_dois option:selected').val());

alert(soma);

})
```

Veja o fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hq8mv7xw/

Você pode fazer o evento para os dois selects também:

```
$('#s_um, #s_dois').change(function() {

var soma = parseInt($('#s_um option:selected').val()) + parseInt($('#s_dois option:selected').val());

alert(soma);

})
```